# Am I pursuing a “degree in” or “of computer science”?

Tags: etiquette, degree

On [my profile](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/111572/micah-nelson?tab=profile), I described my career status as:

> Currently pursuing a degree **in** Computer Science at Temple College.

Is using *in* or *of* the correct preposition used in an academic setting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on English.SE or English Language Learners SE.

Comment: I have always heard "in", never "of".  "Computer Science degree", as Solar Mike suggests, is also correct.

Comment: @NateEldredge: When closing a question, it is irrelevant whether it’s on-topic (or even better suited) somewhere else. The important thing is whether it is off-topic on this site. I fail to see this here. That being said, proofreading is off-topic on any SE site and “the correct way of referencing any academic degree in an academic setting” is far too broad a question. I reduced the question to one we can actually answer.

Comment: As a sidenote: There is no reason to capitalise *computer science* here, since it is not a proper name or part of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context 'in' is right, even if the eventual degree is called "Master of Computer Science". I hold a degree **in** mathematics, but its formal title is 'Master **of** Mathematics'. My first degree, also **in** mathematics was, formally, Bachelor **of** Arts.

There is a distinction between the subject of a degree and its formal title.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers my question.